# Is it possible to add custom locust command line arguments

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I'm wondering if there is a way to pass custom command-line/configuration arguments to locust. I am currently passing in my user credentials into my test as environment variables but I would like to pass them in through the command line with something that would look like this:

```
locust -f <locustfile> --host <host> --username <username> --password  <password>
```

Ideally I would like to avoid creating my own custom extension of locust but I'm gonna guess that I will have to in order to this. I'd be happy to hear any suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! There’s an example on github: https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/add_command_line_argument.py

```
@events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener
def init_parser(parser):
    parser.add_argument(
        '--my-argument',
        help="It's working"
    )

class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    @task
    def my_task(self):
        print(self.environment.parsed_options.my_argument)
```

Comment: Would this also allow me to add custom argument to my config file or would I need to add another listener?

Comment: Yes it should work with config files an env vars as well, but let me know if it doesnt :)

Comment: Its working great, thanks again for all of your help Cyberwiz

Comment: How to access the value passed in a User class?

Comment: it's all there in the linked example, but I added it to my answer now